# Creating a percentile if function in VBA with variables

Tags: vba, conditional-statements, array-formulas, percentile

I'm currently stuck trying to create a function that calculates a percentile with data that meets a criteria. My data is much longer but is in this form:

```
A          B
462        2015
675        2015
494        2014
802        2015
380        2014
```

So in this case, the percentile array is column A and the criteria range is column B. The statement below is calculating the 90th percentile of values in column A that correspond to 2015 in column B. The only way I can get this to work is to have VBA evaluate a statement in quotes using the .formulaArray property. Using the 5 row example above (I think you need more than 5 rows to calculate a percentile):

```
Cells(1, 10).FormulaArray = "=PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(A2:A5 = 2015,B2:B5),0.9)"
```

This works, except for when I substitute the ranges/ values in the function for variables. This does not work:

```
dim lastyear as integer
dim yearcol as range
dim valuescol as range

lastyear = 2015
valuescol = range(cells(1,1),cells(5,1))
yearcol = range(cells(1,2),cells(5,2)

Cells(1, 10).FormulaArray = "=PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(yearcol = lastyear, valuescol,0.9)"
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the variable outside the quotes:

```
dim lastyear as integer
dim yearcol as range
dim valuescol as range

lastyear = 2015
Set valuescol = range(cells(1,1),cells(5,1))
Set yearcol = range(cells(1,2),cells(5,2))

Cells(1, 10).FormulaArray = "=PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(" & yearcol.address(0,0) & " = " & lastyear & ", " & valuescol.address(0,0) & ",0.9)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still getting a type mismatch on the variables. Maybe I have to declare the range variables differently since it is in a formula array?

Comment: @sevans see edit, I forgot that we need to use the address not the range variable itself.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help; you put an end to over an hour of google searches.